# Filter by Score with Ngrams

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search string of `Resta` and currently my results include:

```
"Save at any restaurant!", 
"Save at any gas station!"
```

The reason is because of my index:

```
{
  "rewards": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
              }
            }
          },
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "rewards",
        "creation_date": "1555542654894",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": "2",
              "max_gram": "20"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "ngram_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "Nzf6KNHkQIeKP0HbVFK1lw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6060299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I look at the document with `Save at any gas station!` sure enough I see `sta` as an ngram.

```
{
  "_index": "rewards",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "6",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "took": 0,
  "term_vectors": {
    "name": {
      "field_statistics": {
        "sum_doc_freq": 73,
        "doc_count": 3,
        "sum_ttf": 73
      },
      "terms": {
        "any": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 2,
              "start_offset": 8,
              "end_offset": 11
            }
          ]
        },
        "save": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 0,
              "start_offset": 0,
              "end_offset": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        "sta": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 4,
              "start_offset": 16,
              "end_offset": 23
            }
          ]
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(I omitted many others for brevity)

Query used:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "restaurant",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "category",
          ],
          "operator": "and"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I search I get back a score

```
["Save at any restaurant!", 1.1967528]
["Save at any gas station!", 0.7141209]
```

The user here is in fact looking for `Restaurant` and I'm wondering how to filter or exclude results by score.  I can't seem to find a good definition of score (it seems relative) but how do I not show `Save at any gas station!` here (eventually).

Even giving it a full search phrase of `restaurant`, the scores only get slightly better:

```
["Save at any restaurant!", 1.253743]
["Save at any gas station!", 0.7141209]
```

Comment: Can you share your query as well?? You could opt for using a non-ngram search time analyzer. It will match resta to what you have in your index, since you're using 2-20 ngram size this would only match restaurant

Comment: @ByronVoorbach that might be what I need, I updated my answer with the query. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Yeah spcify a different search analyser for the query (that doesn’t use ngrams) and you’re good to go! More steady results + faster performance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an [Edge-Ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) Analyzer in the mapping and make use of this *only and only* in the search request.

What edge ngram does is it only creates the below tokens using the starting letters of a word.

For e.g. `re, res, rest, resta, restau, restaur, restaura, restauran, restaurant`

I've added an edge n-gram analyzer and notice how I'm not using this analyzer in any of the fields. I would make use of this analyzer *only* during the search query.

That means it would only search the above mentioned tokens of restaurant in inverted index.

Below is a sample mapping and its query.

### Mapping

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "name":{  
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{  
                  "name":{  
                     "type":"text",
                     "analyzer":"ngram_analyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings":{  
      "index":{  
         "number_of_shards":"5",
         "analysis":{  
            "filter":{  
               "ngram_filter":{  
                  "type":"ngram",
                  "min_gram":"2",
                  "max_gram":"20"
               },
               "edgengram_filter":{  
                  "type":"edge_ngram",
                  "min_gram":"2",
                  "max_gram":"20"
               }
            },
            "analyzer":{  
               "ngram_analyzer":{  
                  "filter":[  
                     "lowercase",
                     "ngram_filter"
                  ],
                  "type":"custom",
                  "tokenizer":"standard"
               },
               "edgengram_analyzer":{  
                  "filter":[  
                     "lowercase",
                     "edgengram_filter"
                  ],
                  "type":"custom",
                  "tokenizer":"standard"
               }
            }
         },
         "number_of_replicas":"1"
      }
   }
}
```

Below is how your query would be:

### Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "multi_match":{  
                  "query":"restaurant",
                  "fields":[  
                     "name",
                     "category"
                  ],
                  "operator":"and",
                  "analyzer":"edgengram_analyzer"   <---- Added this
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

You would be able to see the required result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is the right answer but the payloads don't seem to be working, I had to tweak some, can you update and I'll accept? `"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown filter type [edgengram_filter] for [edgengram_filter]"}]`

Comment: @Anthony, I've added the mapping which worked on my ES 5.5.2 version. Please verify and let me know.